Help Needed: Baking Hair Dynamics Crashes Blender - Seeking Solutions for Animation Workflow
I'm working on an animation project using CLO3D, Blender, and Unreal Engine, but I've encountered an issue with Blender freezing when I try to bake hair dynamics for fur.
Workflow:
1.CLO3D: Animate the fabric.
2.Blender: Import the animated fabric as FBX, apply fur using hair particles.
3.Unreal Engine: Export the fur animation from Blender as Alembic and import it into Unreal Engine.
Current Issue:
Blender freezes when I try to bake hair dynamics. The Hair Dynamics Cache option causes Blender to freeze during the baking process.
Previous Issue:
This process worked before, without the need to bake the fur, but when importing the alembic as groom in Unreal Engine (If I don't import as groom, there is no fur in my asset), I loose all my UVs with transparencies and patterns because Unreal doesn't read them, and instead reads it as if it was hair of a person, when its actually a mask with fur, transparencies and colours.
So, I need a way to bake the fur with the UVs before exporting to Unreal Engine. But Blender keeps crushing
Steps I've Tried:
-Reducing the number of particles.
-Simplifying dynamics settings.
-Baking in smaller segments.
How can I bake hair dynamics without Blender freezing?
Are there alternative workflows to efficiently handle and bake fur animation?
How can I maintain UVs with transparencies and patterns when importing the fur into Unreal Engine?
System Specifications:
Operating System: Windows 11
Blender Version: 3.5.1
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 6800H with Radeon Graphics, 3201 MHz, 8 cores, 16 threads
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060
RAM: 32 GB


I've no experience with hair dynamics but you could try updating to a supported version of Blender and see if that helps. The latest LTS version of Blender 3 which should use the same settings as your version is 3.6.14. It looks as if there was a fix for Blender freezing when baking in version 3.6.13 but I don't know whether that was for the same reason as you're seeing.

Hi Jhon, thanks for your answer. I'll try updating and see how it works!
